# change the subtotal dynamically when the quantity changes in shopping cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopping-cart, cart

I just want the javascript code to achieve this simple thing. The subtotal price should be changed according to the quantity the user changes. If the price is 1000 and the quantity is changed to 2 the subtotal should be 2000.

Here is My code :

```
<input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="quantity" value="1">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" value="1000" readonly>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subTotal" value="1000">
</td>
```

I'm zero in javascript. also please show me the way to add the script inside my HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#quantity").change(function(){
        $("#subTotal").val(parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($("#price").val()));
    });
});
```

I have added a plunker for you - http://plnkr.co/edit/aF6G1SSJZTLREH6cBBul

Firstly, add your code in document ready block as it executes your code only after the document is ready. Secondly, bind the onchange event with input field with id quantity and do all the calculations. Please note, you should also do some validations, like if a word is entered or the filed is left blank, etc.

Comment: Yes, you have to specify just like above.

Comment: just adding this code inside my HTML within a script tag will work right?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Just make sure place the script after jquery.js

Comment: @sathyadev - There was some typo in code - I have updated them. Please check now.

Comment: @sathyadev - Did you checked the link? It is working. Also, I updated some code as well after your comment 16 mins ago. Did you picked the updated code?

Comment: yep.. used your updated code.. showing NaN in subTotal when i change the quantity

Comment: @sathyadev - It should work as I have created a plunker and shared in my answer as well. Can you share your code snippet

Comment: sorry works fine now.. :) thanks alot for this.. much appreciated.. and sorry for the dumb questions..

Comment: @sathyadev - great it worked for you. I did not find your question dumb. You ought to ask question. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend starting from the basics if you want to do this often:

http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript

If it is just a one time thing you can hire some one to do it for you.